# .net core Unable to open sqlite db file on linux

Tags: c#, linux, autofac, .net-core, self-hosting

I build web app use .net core 1.1 . When i run on linux, i got error  Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'. It works on Windows

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
      string connectionString = string.Format("Data source={0}/data/database.db;", 
        m_container.Resolve<IHostingEnvironment>().WebRootPath);      
      builder.Register(c => new TVDbContext(connectionString));
      builder.RegisterType<FolderStore>().As<IFolderStore>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
      builder.RegisterType<FileInfoStore>().As<IFileInfoStore>();
```

Configure

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {     

      // Add framework services.
      services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

      services.AddMvc();
      services.AddMemoryCache();

      //Autofac config
      var globalContainer = TV.Core.DependencyInject.GlobalContainer.Instance;

      ApplicationContainer = globalContainer.Container;

      var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
      builder.Populate(services);
      builder.Update(ApplicationContainer);      

      new DependencyInjectRegister(ApplicationContainer).Register();

      var fileScanner = TV.Core.DependencyInject.TVContext.Context.Get<IFileInfoScanner>();
      fileScanner.ScanFile();

      // Create and return the service provider.
      return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
    }
```

Comment: i've got the same error, did you figure out how to fix it?

Comment: case-sensitive on linux